# Transmission advertising IPv6 address despite not being bound to it

Tags: ipv6, transmission

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 and transmission-daemon 2.94-2ubuntu3.  Transmission is connected to a VPN over IPv4, and that works fine, except that — despite passing `--bind-address-ipv6 fe80::` to transmission-daemon — Transmission is somehow still advertising my IPv6 address.  I can tell via a Torrent IP checker and also by the fact that my web server has recently been getting `/announce` requests with my IPv6 address in the query parameters for one of the torrents I'm seeding.  `sudo netstat -tulpan` shows that Transmission is only listening over IPv4.

How do I get Transmission to stop advertising my IPv6 address?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a bug in Transmission that was fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/pull/265), merged on January 20, but (as of 2022-02-27) not yet published in a release.